# How to properly use inheritance and polymorphism - Queues implemented as arrays

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I just needed a little help with inheritance and polymorphism. We're working on queues & stacks, and were asked to implement them as arrays so we understand them properly, instead of just using Java's methods.

The task is to implement a Shuffling and Circular queue as subclasses of a general Queue class.

**A Shuffling or Linear Queue:** Arranges data in a sequential order, one after another. The solution is to shift all elements up by 1 after dequeuing the first value, causing a "Shuffling Effect".

**A Circular Queue:** A circular queue "chases the front" and cycles around the array when the front passes the 'end' of the array. It arranges data similar to a circle, with the last element connecting back to the first element.

I first implemented just the shuffling queue as a class of its own, and got it working properly. Here's the first section of code:

```
public class myQueue
{
    //class fields
    private Object[] queue; 
    private int rear, front, maxSize;  
    public static final int DefaultCap = 100; 

    //default constructor
    public myQueue()
    {
        maxSize = DefaultCap; 
        queue = new Object[DefaultCap]; 
        rear = 0;
        front = 0; 
    }

    //alternate Constructor
    public myQueue(int maxCapacity)
    {
        if(maxCapacity < 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Capacity cannot be negative");
        }
        else
        {
            queue = new Object[maxCapacity];
            maxSize = maxCapacity;
            rear = 0;
            front = 0; 
        }
    }
```

I also have methods in there like `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` etc.

Can't quite wrap my head around how I'm going to use the parameters from my parent class like rear, front, capacity. Do they need to be public?

At the moment, I've got:

```
public class ShufflingQueue extends MyQueue 
{

    public ShufflingQueue(int Capacity)
    {
        super(Capacity); 
    }
    
    public void enqueue(Object n)
    {
        super.enqueue(n);
    }

    public void dequeue()
    {
        super.dequeue();
    }

    public int getSize()
    {
        return super.getSize(); 
    }
}
```

At the moment, the above is fine and it works as I expect it to. However, this is because I still have `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` as part of the parent class. I'm supposed to change it so that my shuffling queue and circular queue have different methods for enqueue and dequeue. I know the *code* to enqueue and dequeue, for both Shuffling and Circular queues but I'm not sure how to have these different methods for the two queues. And how would I be able to use `rear`, `front` from my parent class. Would I need new class fields for rear, front and capacity in my subclasses as well?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I've edited your question to remove some "fluff" that isn't really relevant.  One thing your question is missing is a description of the "shuffling" and "circular" queues - those aren't standard data type terms, so we'll need more information about what those are supposed to do.

Comment: @BJMyers, a "circular queue" (https://www.google.com/search?q=circular%22+queues) is a standard datatype term.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I've updated it with the required information now :)